# What happened to the string-manipulation tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[string-manipulation](/questions/tagged/string-manipulation) just disappeared today. Actually I'm just curious, what happened to it?

Personally I liked it :).

**UPDATE:** After discussing this issue with @Lance, I decided to ask the mods to unsynonym [string-manipulation](/questions/tagged/string-manipulation) from [string](/questions/tagged/string). It was a very useful tag.

Comment: I'm curious in your reasoning why `string` should be kept separate from `string-manipulation`. How many questions are there about strings that don't involve manipulating or interacting with them in some way?

Comment: @Cody: questions regarding string encoding probably deserve [tag:string] (in addition to [tag:encoding]) but not [tag:string-manipulation].

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Hmm, that's a plausible suggestion. But I still disagree. I think the `encoding` tag is sufficient there. If I'm interested in questions about encoding, it doesn't matter if the question is about string or character encoding: both are potentially useful to me.

Comment: @Cody: I'm not entirely convinced myself either ;-) All the examples I could think of include a second tag that kind-of makes [tag:string] superfluous. [tag:parsing] might be similar, as would be [tag:regex]. In essence, [tag:string-manipulation] implies string *construction* for me. Parsing/analyzing/... strings is not [tag:string-manipulation].

Comment: @Cody, `type` questions.

Comment: @Cody `string` is very very general. If we follow this logic, we could wipe out the 90% of tags on SO. To me, `string-manipulation` is when you are trying to change the contents of a string (or construct a string as @Joachim says). It can be done by regex, simple replacing methods or any other way. The usage of this tag seemed very logical to me, and gave much more information about a question than a simple `string` tag.

Comment: @Lance: Questions about string **types** should probably include a tag identifying the particular language being discussed. String types don't really exist in abstractions outside of a particular framework. And if that's the case, then I don't understand what value the string tag actually adds to the question.

Comment: @Cody, I think the [tag:string] is too vague to be useful, and adds no value.  I was just bringing up an example that wasn't string manipulation.

Comment: I also remember this tag fondly -- it earned the taxonomist badge for me once upon a time.  But as for the encoding comments: that just another way of manipulating a string.  You are manipulating it so that is encoded how you want.  The construction comments also imply specific platforms: many platforms still use mutable strings, after all.  I think the best example so far is parsing; you might parse a string to create a high-level object and never manipulate the original string at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading through the comments, I think that [string](/questions/tagged/string) should probably be done away with entirely. Having a few more specific tags such as [string-manipulation](/questions/tagged/string-manipulation), [string-encoding](/questions/tagged/string-encoding),[string-internment](/questions/tagged/string-internment) seems like a much more useful system of organization that would *actually tell people something* about the content of the question.

Comment: What's wrong with just... "encoding"? (given that there are only five questions on the entire site that even *mention* internment, we probably don't need to bother creating tags for that)

Comment: @Shog - I wasn't really advocating for those exact tags, I was just trying to think of possible subsets of the current `string` tag that would be more informative about the tag's scope.

Comment: You can usually figure that out from *the other tags*! I mean... [tag:c#] is pretty broad too, but only a few foolhardy souls suggest divvying it up into [subsets based on usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-dynamic).

Comment: @Shog9: The argument is that (unlike [tag:c#]) [tag:string] doesn't really mean much about the question, since practically any non-trivial program uses strings somewhere. It would be like having a tag for "program" or "computer", though less extreme.

Comment: @Mechanical: there's a difference between most programs using strings *somewhere* and using them in a context that applies to the question. Plenty of questions that have nothing to do with strings. Better analogy might be [tag:math], something crucial to every program ever, but not the focus of every question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't support this. If you could explain the difference between a question tagged string, and one tagged string-manipulation, that would be a start in making your case for it.

Comment: If anything, I would think `string` is a synonym for `string-manipulation`, rather than vice versa.

Comment: @Joel: you're probably right, but either way there's no need for *separate* tags. And... "string" is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody decided to synonym it to [string](/questions/tagged/string), which doesn't seem right, but it's done now.

I thought it was a good tag to narrow down the exact sphere of programming you were looking for.

Comment: Hm, that sounds very strange. Can anything be done about this?

Comment: @baz, you can appeal to the mods to unsynonym it.  Maybe turn this question into a request.  Use the tags `support` and `synonym-request`.

Comment: Thanks @Lance, haven't used Meta a lot. I will do that.